# How to bind an action after customer login success using Magento?

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, login, cookie, ce-1.4.1.1

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1. After logout success, customer is rooted to "logout.phtml" first and "home page" later.

Is there anyway I could make Magento run couple of "php" codes after "login" success ?

Please don't hesitate to provide code samples as I'm new in Magento.

/var/www/app/etc/modules/Lpf_ModuleCookie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModuleCookie>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lpf_ModuleCookie>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/var/www/app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModuleCookie>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Lpf_ModuleCookie>
    </modules>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <customer_login>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>ModuleCookie/observer</class>
                    <method>customerLogin</method>
                </customer_login>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</config>
```

/var/www/app/code/local/Lpf/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer
{
     /**
      * Run couple of 'php' codes after customer logs in
      *
      * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
      */
     public function customerLogin($observer)
     {
         Mage::log(__METHOD__ . '() Hello!'); // Remove afterwards. Check your var/log/system.log to see if came to this point
         $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
         // "run couple of 'php' codes"
     }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` model's method `setCustomerAsLoggedIn()` an event `customer_login` is being dispatched. I guess you need to hook in on that event. You could do this as follows.

Add the event to your module's `config.xml` file (app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModuleCookie>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Lpf_ModuleCookie>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <lpf_modulecookie>
                <class>Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model</class>
            </lpf_modulecookie>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <lpf_modulecookie_customer_login>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>lpf_modulecookie/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </lpf_modulecookie_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now create a model `Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer` (app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/Model/Observer.php). Add a `customerLogin()` method to the class:

```
class Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer
{

     /**
      * Run couple of 'php' codes after customer logs in
      *
      * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
      */
     public function customerLogin($observer)
     {
         Mage::log(__METHOD__ . '() Hello!'); // Remove afterwards. Check your var/log/system.log to see if came to this point
         $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
         // "run couple of 'php' codes"
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In what location should I put the class "class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer" ? I don't find "config.xml". Do you know where it is located ?

Comment: You need to learn how to write your own module. There's lots of tutorials online about his: https://www.google.nl/search?q=magento%20create%20your%20own%20module pick one. You will find out what "config.xml" is and where to put Model classes. I added the path's to the files I mentioned in my answer to give you some directions.

Comment: I have followed everything. I can't see whether my new module works fine as I don't find "var/log/system.log". Could you tell me where it is located ?

Comment: Logging should be turned on in System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = "Yes". Also `var/` should be writable.

Comment: No "system.log" file is created after login success. I can't find what went wrong. I have provided my modules files...

Comment: `<events/>` should go either under `<frontend/>` or `<global/>`. Also you should define your module classpath first or else Magento can't find your Model classes. I've updated my answer. I hope this is what your looking for and you can accept this

Comment: system.log is created. I cant't find any "Hello!" inside though...

Comment: hey i fallowed your answer but it did not work for me

Comment: You should [Ask a new question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and provide all the code you have written

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
    }
}
```