# Custom session variable when customer log in

Tags: login, customer-session

I am trying to add an extra field in customer login page and save it as session variable when customer logins successfully.

I add the line in the loginPostAction function however I can't get the values in the frontend.

The variable called passcode

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password']) && !empty($login['passcode'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password'], $login['passcode']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Set in session

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->setPasscode($login['passcode']);
```

Get in session

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($session) {
   $session->getPasscode();
}
```

Comment: How can I extend loginPostAction() function without editing the core file? Shall I create a module for that ? @Abdul

Comment: pls follow this : http://mattmcalear.net/magento-event-observers-user-login/

Comment: or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento

Comment: Thank you for your help and answers, I have created the module however somehow it is not working, therefore I have cretead another question, maybe you may help me on this [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92871/create-session-variable-to-customer-login-action) @Abdul