# Create session variable to customer login action

Tags: event-observer, customer-session

I am trying to hook a session variable to customer login event with the help of this tutorial http://mattmcalear.net/magento-event-observers-user-login/

I have created the module but it is not showing the custom session variable value in the frontend.
What am I doing wrong?

/app/etc/modules/Designota_Savepasscode.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Designota_Savepasscode>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Designota_Savepasscode>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Designota/Savepasscode/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Designota_Savepasscode>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Designota_Savepasscode>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <designota_savepasscode>
                <class>Designota_Savepasscode_Model</class>
            </designota_savepasscode>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
              <observers>
                  <designota_savepasscode>
                      <class>designota_savepasscode/observer</class>
                      <method>customerLogin</method>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                  </designota_savepasscode>
              </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Designota/Savepasscode/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Designota_Savepasscode_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $session->setPasscode($login['passcode']);
    }
}
```

In the frontend I use the below code for getting the session variable

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($session) {
    $session->getPasscode();
}
```

Comment: Isn't `$login['passcode']` an undefined variable here ?

Comment: `$login['passcode']` is an extra required field in login form where customer will enter. @Prateek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as your comment in order to check passcode variable.you need to use

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('variable');
```

So,for this case you need to use

`$login=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam(('login');`

`$passcode=$login['passcode'];`

Comment: thank you for your answer however it didn't work. the input field in the login.phtml is `<input type="passcode" name="login[passcode]" class="input-text required-entry" id="passcode" title="<?php echo $this->__('Passcode') ?>" />` I just want to save the value of this input field as a session variable and use it in the frontend. @Amit Bera

Comment: pleasew ckd now