# Show catalog based on the custom category attribute

Tags: category, catalog

I have a custom category attribute called passcode and it is unique for every category. (with the help of this [tutorial](http://gauss-development.com/blog/tutorials/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento/)

When a customer logins (there is an addition field in the login.phtml for the passcode which will be stored in a session variable), magento will only display that specific category which has the entered passcode.

I have already created a custom field in the login.phtml and hooks it to customer login action (here is the [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92871/create-session-variable-to-customer-login-action/92877)) how can I redirect customer to that specific category only which has the same passcode with the customer entered one?

The customer will only see the entered passcode category and its products, and not be able to see any other category and products.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and here it is:

```
public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $login = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('login');
    $passcode = $login['passcode'];
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setPasscode($passcode);

    $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('passcode', $passcode);
    $categories->addUrlRewriteToResult();
    $categories->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
    $categories->load();

    if ($categories->getFirstItem()) {
        $category = $categories->getFirstItem();

        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false)
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl($category->getURL($category));  
        else             
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());

        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');         

    }
    else {
        echo 'No category exists with the name ' . $name;
    }
}

public function customerLogout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->unsPasscode();
}
```