# How can I redirect to particular page after login in checkout process?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

I have **two themes** e.g. **mobile and desktop**.
**For mobile theme** I have **separated the first step of the checkout process** i.e. Login step to different page.
Like
page no.1-from basket page a person goto the login page(login or checkout as guest).
    So here the file present in "**chekout/onepage/login.phtml**" is getting rendered.

page no.2-The next step is to calculate delivery method and delivery options in a page.
page no.3-Then the payment method page and finally the checkout process.

So **I want when a person go to the page no. 1 (i.e. login page) and give the email and password and click the login button , then the person will redirected to the page no.2(delivery method and options)**.

*But it Redirects to the account dashboard page*.

Below is the code for the login and redirect which is located at ..
core/Mage/Customer/controller/AccountContorller.php

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}

/**
 * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
 */
protected function _loginPostRedirect()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {
        // Set default URL to redirect customer to
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
        // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {echo "gone";exit;
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
                Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
            )) {
                $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                if ($referer) {
                    // Rebuild referer URL to handle the case when SID was changed
                    $referer = Mage::getModel('core/url')
                        ->getRebuiltUrl(Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer));
                    if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                    }
                }
            } else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
            }
        } else {echo "go";exit;
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
        }
    } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
    } else {
        if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
        }
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
        }
    }

    $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
}
```

How can I **change the redirection** to a particular page **after login step** for mobile theme only ?
Is it possible to redirect to different url for different theme in a single store from the same method ?
Or
Is it required to override the customer module ?
How can I override the redirect method of customer to redirect to particular page ?

Comment: see this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58951/48564), you can use an observer after login event

Answer (score 0):

go to *persistent/customer/form/login.phtml* or *customer/form/login.phtml* and add the following into the form:

```
<?php if (Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('frontend') == "your_mobile_theme"): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="referer_url" value="your_page_url"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

please let me know if it's ok

Comment: But the login form I am talking about is supposed to be present at..mypackage/iphone/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You first need to set "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" to "No" as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

And in the "checkout/onepage/login.phtml" change form action as mentioned below.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost',array('referer' => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode('page no.2 url'))) ?>" method="post">
```

Here you can do by another way.

write a basic custome module and register an event for customer_login in the frontend area as below

```
<frontend>
  <events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <your_module>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>redirectLogin</method>
            </your_module>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
</events>
</frontend>
```

After that, create an observer class and write below function.

```
public function redirectLoginLogin($observer)
{
  $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
  if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') ===   false)
  {       
    $session->setAfterAuthUrl('Your page 2 url');
  } 
  else 
  {
    $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());
  }
  $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
}
```