# How to send an Confirmation email when customer has login successfully?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, login

I want to send a confirmation mail to the customer when has customer login. Please let me know how can I achieve it. I am using Magento 1.9.2.

this is my `_loginPostRedirect()` function code

```
 protected function _loginPostRedirect()
{
    // send mail after login start here
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $templateId = 2; // USE YOUR OWN TEMPLATE ID
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');  
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');  
    $sender = array('name' => $senderName,
        'email' => $senderEmail);
    $recepientEmail = $customer->getEmail();
    $recepientName = $customer->getName();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $vars = array('customerName' => $customer->getName()); 
     Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
// send mail after login end here
```

Comment: customer will get email  after successful login.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind an action after customer login success using Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override Account controller,

First copy AccountController.php

From

```
/app/code/code/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

To

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

Here you will find method: **_loginPostRedirect()**

Here  you can put confirmation mail code.

Comment: i fallow your instruction but its not working

Comment: Yes you have to create

Comment: You tried with this ? :-----http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create a module, you can override Account controller using the following steps:

1) Make a New Email Template from **Transactional Emails** and note the ID of it.

```
hello {{var customerName}},
    You are succesfully logged in.
Thank you
```

2) Copy AccountController.php file
From: `/app/code/code/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`

To:   `/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`

3) Search for method: `_loginPostRedirect()` in `AccountController.php`

and put the below code at the start of this function

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$templateId = 8; // USE YOUR OWN TEMPLATE ID
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');  
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');  
$sender = array('name' => $senderName,
            'email' => $senderEmail);
$recepientEmail = $customer->getEmail();
$recepientName = $customer->getName();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$vars = array('customerName' => $customer->getName()); 
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
```

Comment: we have chat on this topic have you deleted can you share that.

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to create an Observer for the `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost` event:

```
     <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost>
        <observers>
            <module_postdispatch_customer_account_loginpost>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>postLogin</method>
            </module_postdispatch_customer_account_loginpost>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost>
```

and check in the `postLogin` function if the customer is logged in:

```
if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
   // send mail to customer
}
```

Your final structure sould be:

```
app/code/local/<namespace>/<module>/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/<namespace>/<module>/Model/Observer.php
```

Comment: You need to create a new module, google how to to it with creating new observer.
e.g. http://magenticians.com/create-magento-custom-module/#crayon-5860e3ef69551229380652

Comment: Added a little more information in the answer