# How to redirect to previous page after login?

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect

I've set `no` on `system configuration`-> `customer login configuration`. But nothing's happen, it still direct to my account dashboard.

How to redirect to previous page after login?

Comment: Have you this setting on website level and store level ??

Comment: on my website level, because there's no option to do that on my store level. @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: So You have done this  changes in both website level and global level  ??

Comment: yes, I have done. But after i logged in, it still direct to account dashboard page

Answer (score 1):

Set **NO** on **System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options**

Then in your login.phtml files (both, persistent/customer/form and customer/form on your template folder), change the action of your `<form>` to:

```
action="<?php echo str_replace('login', 'loginPost', $this->helper('customer')->getLoginUrl()) ?>"
```

But remember, DO NOT EDIT THE CORE! Create a custom extension to accomplish this job.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099279/5810265

Comment: I don't know why when I set "no" my login page is not give an alert when I insert wrong password

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh I think you will have a problem with core files!

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite in local `loginPostAction()` from `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` to `app/code/local/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` Then you put this :

```
 public function loginPostAction(){

    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('wlc_business');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    // The adding code here
    $this->_redirectReferer(); //redirect you to the previous page
    $this->_redirect('/'); // redirect you to the home page
    $this->_redirect('wishlist'); //redirect you to wishlist page for exemple
}
```

Comment: I don't know why when I set "no" my login page is not give an alert when I insert wrong password

Comment: Either the problem comes from the theme, or you have removed the block that displays the messages`$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();` or the controller if you had modified it, please compare with my controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can customer_login observer. After customer has logged in, you can redirect the customer where you want.

Here is how to create observer for customer login
[How to bind an action after customer login success using Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento)

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code to back to prev page after login

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$url = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$loginUrl = $url->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => base64_encode($url->getCurrentUrl())));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>">Login</a>
```

Comment: OP has asked for M1, not M2 :) but nice to know for m2...

Comment: Dont use object manager even in M2