# Send an email to Admin when a User logins in frontend into his account. magento 2

Tags: magento2

send an email to Admin when a User logins in frontend into his account. magento 2, using event  and observer

Comment: You can get your answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento

Comment: @KingshukDeb This answer for the Magento 1, but question is about Magento 2.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau have given the answer for magento2 !!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So here it is.

```
                 // CODE NOT TESTED.
```

**Your event is `customer_customer_authenticated`. And the dispatched method is this.**

```
$this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_customer_authenticated',
            ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
        );
```

Create a file inside the given path `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/events.xml`. Add the below code inside that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="customer_customer_authenticated">
       <observer name="customer_customer_authenticated_email" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\SendEmailAfterLogin" />
   </event>
</config>
```

After that create a file again in this path `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Observer/SendEmailAfterLogin.php`. And the code will be this

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

class SendEmailAfterLogin implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
     // send email from here//
     // If you want to load template by id then try to do this.
     // Use Magento\Email\Model\Template; Create the constructor as per that 
     // and use loadDefault($templateId) function to load a template. 
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the function to give you an idea. Its not a full code but you will get the idea how to do that.