# Session is not working in cron file

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, customer-session, magento-cron

```
namespace send\sms\Cron; 

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Run  /*extends send\sms\Controller\Customr*/  {

   public function execute()
   {

    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
     if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

         $idd =$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

     }
       $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');  
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
    //$sql = "UPDATE `total_cashback` SET is_active= 100 WHERE user_id = '801' ";  
     $sql = "UPDATE `wallet_discounts` SET is_active = 12000 WHERE customer_id = $idd ";  
    $connection->query($sql);
   }



}
```

Cannot get customer Id in the above snippet.

Comment: Can you tell me what you are trying to achive using above code?

Comment: I'm trying to update is_active column for logged in customer. But cannot get customer id in cron jobs.plz help me

Comment: You can not access customer session in cron. You could try to create an observer for 'customer_login' and do your logic within the observer. Eg in M1 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento

Comment: I'm not experienced in M1. So can you please tell me how to use cron in observers

Answer (score 1):

You can not access customer session in cron (not impossible, but very hard to do). You could try creating an observer for `customer_login` and add your custom logic there.

To create an observer for `customer_login`

in app/code/Send/Sms/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="send_sms_customer_login" instance="Send\Sms\Observer\Frontend\CustomerLoginObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In Send\Sms\Observer\Frontend\CustomerLoginObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Send\Sms\Observer\Frontend;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class CustomerLoginObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId()
        //custom logic here
    }
}
```

If you want to go the cron route, you could take a look at how Magento implement the "Customers Now Online" feature in Admin -> Customers -> Now Online.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really helpful. But I need to get id of the user from session and make a crob job function for that specific user.

Comment: You could use the above logic to store information into a db and then run a cron against that db.